# How to enable a button in aspx when a user types into a textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In an aspx page i need to do a validation where i need to enable a button when user types into a particular textbox

Comment: Nothing. I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this client-side, in JavaScript, such as (if you're using jQuery):

```
var $textbox = $('#yourTextboxId');

var content = $textbox.val(); // Get your original textbox value

$textbox.keyup(function() { 
    if ($textbox.val() != content) { // Text has changed, enable your button
        content = $textbox.val();
        $('#yourButtonId').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

As a side-note, with .NET, you'll need to use `ClientIDMode="Static"` on your controls (such as TextBox) in order to get a static ID to use with JavaScript, otherwise the above code won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your input text box with id "textBox"

```
<input type="text" id="textBox" />
```

Your button with id "btn1" which is initially disabled.

```
<button type="button" id="btn1" disabled="disabled">Button</button>
```

The javascript that will enable or disable the button

```
$("#textBox").change(function() {
   if ($("#textBox").val() != "")
   {
      $("#btn1").removeAttr("disabled");
   }
   else
   {
      $("#btn1").attr("disabled", "disabled");
   }
}
```

Comment: So, if the textbox value is not "" (has text in it), then disable the button?

Comment: Yeah, this check can be replaced by any condition he wants. The code was just to give him some idea on how to achieve the task.

Answer (score 0):

Here is My [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/prabhu5013/pec46/)

```
 $('#TextBoxId').keyup(function () {
            if ($.trim($(this).val()) != '') {
                $('#ButtonId').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
            else {
                $('#ButtonId').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        });
```